# How to deploy beta version on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment

I want to be able to display some temporary web site at the url: http://example.com
and also be able to display some test version at http://beta.example.com
In both cases it must be port 80.
What are the options?

Option 1 which I was thinking of could be:
first site is located in inetpub/wwwroot binded to localhost:80
second site is located in inetpub/second  binded to beta.example.com:80
and then it would require some additional changes of some settings (did not try it yet, but sounds too complicated)

Option 2 (not sure if it will work)
first site is located in intetpub/wwwroot , binded to localhost:80
Second site is located in interpub/wwwroot/second, converted to webapp(?) and binded to beta.example.com:80  ?

Comment: That's the typical IIS multi site setup https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background and the web content folders can be set to anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below opntions to implement your reuiqrmnet.

1. create two web site in your and assign site bidnidng with the different host name.

sample:

site 1- hostname: example.com,  port number: 80 , IP: 1.2.3

beta site - hostname: beta.example.com,  port number: 80 , IP: 1.2.3

2. host beta version under the same site as application and use URL rewrite to rewrite the page with the application and subdomain

Comment: Thanks, I got this idea before I read your comment and it worked :)

Comment: @JoeDoe If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.